# trigger label when I clicked label children in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a reusable upload component.

```js
const Uploader = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input id="sample" type="file" style={{ display: "none" }} />
      <label htmlFor="sample">
        {children}
      </label>   
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Uploader>
        <button>Upload File</button>
      </Uploader>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I expected that would be opened file directory when I clicked the `Upload File` Button.

But it doesn't work.

How can I make it work as I want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-breeze-nxi1q6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: File select dialog is opening for me.

Comment: @Inder Have you opend codesandbox? and you have to click the second button.

Comment: on pressing choose file, the file select dialog opens. Do you want to set some operation on upload file button?

Comment: @Inder oh. yes,, I would like to use the second button as an upload operator.

Comment: where do you want to upload file?

Comment: @Inder, where I want to upload is not important. I just want to open file directory.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by file directory. When I click on choose file button, file selection dialog is opening up..
Do you want the file path?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Uploader id="first-file" labelText="upload the first" />
    </div>
  );
}
const Uploader = ({ id, labelText }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id} style={{background: '#eee', padding: '5px 10px', borderRadius: '10px', cursor: 'pointer'}}>{labelText}</label>
      <input id={id} type="file" style={{display: 'none'}} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to pass the props as <Component /> not "string".